# Declaring PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS

Tags: java, winapi

Here are my **PSAPI.java** interface:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

    public interface PsApi extends StdCallLibrary {

        public static abstract class PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS extends Structure {

            public int cb;
            public int PageFaultCount;
            public int PeakWorkingSetSize;
            public int WorkingSetSize;
            public int QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
            public int QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
            public int QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
            public int QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
            public int PagefileUsage;
            public int PeakPagefileUsage;
        }

        boolean GetProcessMemoryInfo(HANDLE process, PsApi pmem, int cb);
    }
```

**Another version (without abstract):**

```
public static class PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS extends Structure {

    public int cb;
    public int PageFaultCount;
    public int PeakWorkingSetSize;
    public int WorkingSetSize;
    public int QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public int PagefileUsage;
    public int PeakPagefileUsage;
    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

To use `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` function I should declare variable:

```
PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmem;
```

But it returns an error:

> PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS cannot be resolved to a type

How to include PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS structure properly?
Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason to declare class PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS `abstract`?

Comment: Without abstract parameter (`public static class PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS extends Structure {...`) I get an error **The type PsApi.PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS must implement the inherited abstract method Structure.getFieldOrder()**. On the other hand, I can use another code version (the post has been updated).

Comment: PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS is a pointer. PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS is a structure.

Comment: Hi @MarkKorzhov, did you ever get this working? I'd like to read memory usage of a process in Windows, from a Java program.

Comment: @WouterLievens, see answer below - it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

At the request of commentators, I post a code snippet that shows a list of running processes (id, process name, the number of threads):

```
public class windows {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();

        try {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
                HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010,
                        false, 0);
                if (process != null) {
                    int len = psapi.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, null, path,
                            1024);
                    if (len > 0)
                        System.out.println(new String(path, 0, len));
                    else
                        System.out.println("GetModuleFileNameW failed");
                } else
                    System.out.println("OpenProcess failed");

                System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t"
                        + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile) + "\t"
                        + processEntry.cntThreads);
            }
        } finally {
            kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
}
```

Using Process ID (see [JNA API Documentation](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/)), you can get memory usage of the each process.